# Double click event on 2 different items still triggers

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an item from 1 list move to a second list when it is double clicked. Then when you single click it, move it back to the first list.

The problem I encountered with this is that when rapidly clicking items in the second list, double click events will trigger, despite not clicking on the same item.

You can witness the problem in this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9afn4s7q/

```
$('.item').dblclick(function () {
  $(this).detach();
  $('#list2').append($(this));
  $(this).click(function () {
    $(this).detach();
    $('#list1').append($(this));
  });
});
```

How do I stop a double click event from triggering when clicking different items?

Comment: Another bug I've found: keep clicking on one item in your first list and your list items cycle through like a treadmill.

Comment: check this it might be helpful http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Comment: @Drew Kennedy, Anything that happens in the first list is not important :-) I am aware of this. The problem is only that double click events get triggered even when clicking 2 different DOM elements.

Comment: No worries - Just making sure you were aware. :)

Comment: Any particular reason that you're using `jQuery 1.6.4` in your fiddle? Are you "stuck" with this version?

Comment: @sbeliv01, I am stuck with this version.

Comment: Instead of nesting events, you should just delegate it: https://jsfiddle.net/poypk5c2/1  And be aware, `detach()` is useless in your code

Comment: @A.Wolff All of that is irrelevant to the actual problem. The code that is in the jsfiddle is a reproduction of a bug that I have encountered in my application. The question is only related to the double click event triggering on 2 different items. Anything else is irrelevant. Your jsfiddle does not solve the problem I encountered.

Comment: @JREN Then you should change your code because here you are trying to fix bad coding, nesting events. And on which browser do you encounter the dblclick getting fired on 2 different items? I'm not able to replicate it on chrome but i know IE (older version?!) get some bug regarding this event. But please don't tell us you need to support IE5?!  EDIT: sorry, i'm able to replicate issue

Comment: @JREN One option would be to append the element with a very slight delay (in doing so, the double click event isn't fired since the element hasn't been appended yet) - https://jsfiddle.net/90LbL2fa/

Comment: @JoshCrozier I wish I could tell you how dirty that fix is. But it works, and that's better than what I and anyone else so far came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because the `dbclick` event is still being fired after the element is appended.

In other words, when clicking on an item in the second list, the second click event is being fired at approximately the same time as the `dbclick` event. To work around this, you could compare the event timestamps in order to determine if the second `click` event fired a `dbclick` event after it was appended.

In the example below, the `lastClickTimeStamp` variable is updated each time the `click` event is fired. In order to prevent the weird behavior that you are seeing, a check is made to determine whether the last click was fired before the `dbclick` event is fired.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/g6wyb59d/)

```
var lastClickTimeStamp = 0;
$('#list1').on('dblclick', '.item', function(event) {
  if (event.timeStamp > lastClickTimeStamp) {
    $('#list2').append(this);
  }
});
$('#list2').on('click', '.item', function(event) {
  lastClickTimeStamp = event.timeStamp + 100;
  $('#list1').append(this);
});
```

Side notes:

- I added `100ms` to account for potential timestamp approximations. It's possible for the event timestamps to vary by as little as `1ms`.
- I used event delegation in order to avoid the nested event listeners (although you were already aware of that).
- Since you're using jQuery version 1.6.4, you would use the `.delegate()` method instead of the `.on()` method.

---

As I pointed out in the comments, you could alternatively append the element to the first list with a delay. In doing so, the delegated `dbclick` event isn't fired.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/seLLj5hv/)

```
$('#list1').on('dblclick', '.item', function(event) {
  $('#list2').append(this);
});
$('#list2').on('click', '.item', function(event) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#list1').append(this);
  }.bind(this), 5);
});
```

I feel like both of these solutions are relatively hackish, but nonetheless, they seem to work.

Comment: It seems there is no real way to avoid the 'dirty hack' feeling for this bug.